# Evaluate $\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}}$$

Let $t=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t^2}e^{-\frac{1}{t}}$$

Let $r=\frac{1}{t}$

$$\lim_{r\to \infty}r^2 e^{-r}=\lim_{r\to \infty}\frac{r^2}{e^r}$$

using l'hopital
$$\lim_{r\to \infty}\frac{2r}{e^r}$$

using l'hopital again
$$\lim_{r\to \infty}\frac{2}{e^r}=0$$

Is the following valid? is there is a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

By spherical coordinates $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=r\to 0$

$$\frac{1}{ x^2+y^2+z^2 }e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}}=\frac1{r^2}e^{-\frac1r}$$

and for $y=\frac1r\to \infty$ since eventually $e^y\ge y^3$

$$\frac1{r^2}e^{-\frac1r}=\frac{y^2}{e^y}\le\frac{y^2}{y^3}=\frac1y\to 0$$

Comment: and then to set $t=\frac{1}{r}$ to use l'hopital?

Comment: you can also set 1/r=y

Comment: You don't need l'Hopital, t suffices observe that eventually $e^y>y^3$

Answer (score 2):

All is well.

A comment, instead of using L'Hopital twice:

Let $r \gt 0:$

$e^r \ge 1+ r +r^2/(2!) + r^3/(3!)+....\ge r^3/(3!).$

Then $0\lt \dfrac{r^2}{e^r} \lt \dfrac{r^2}{(r^3/(3!))}= \dfrac{3!}{r}.$

Now consider $r \rightarrow \infty$ , squeeze .

Answer (score 1):

It is valid, yes, and I suppose that that's how I would have done it. Also, I would have written $\lim_{t\to0^+}$ and $\lim_{r\to+\infty}$ instead of  $\lim_{t\to0}$ and $\lim_{r\to\infty}$ respectively.

Comment: $t\to 0^{+}$ because of the domain of the square root?